# Mongoose - Find from 2 collections

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to search 2 models at the same time in a `find()`.

What I have:

```
const one = await Model1.find()
    .where('example').equals('test')
    .limit(limit * 1)
    .skip((page - 1) * limit)
    .sort({ created_at: desc })
    .exec()

const two = await Model2.find()
    .where('example').equals('test')
    .limit(limit * 1)
    .skip((page - 1) * limit)
    .sort({ created_at: desc })
    .exec()
```

But, this returns 2 pages worth of results. Thereotically what I need (I know this code is not valid):

```
const models = [Model1, Model2]

const result = await models.find()
    .where('example').equals('test')
    .limit(limit * 1)
    .skip((page - 1) * limit)
    .sort({ created_at: desc })
    .exec()
```

To return only 1 page of results, including results from both collections - both limited, skipped & sorted in the same way.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an aggregation with [$unionWith](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/) to merge the two collections and query them together

```js
const result = await Model1.aggregate([
  { $match: { example: 'test' } },
  {
    $unionWith: {
      coll: 'model2',
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: { example: 'test' },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  { $sort: { $created_at: -1 } },
  { $limit: limit * 1 },
  { $skip: (page - 1) * limit },
]);
```